# python prettytable module raise Could not determine delimiter error for valid csv file

Tags: python, csv, prettytable

I'm trying to use prettytable module to print out data from csv file. But it failed with the following exception

> Could not determine delimiter error for valid csv file

```
>>> import prettytable
>>> with file("/tmp/test.csv") as f:
...     prettytable.from_csv(f)
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/prettytable.py", line 1337, in from_csv
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/csv.py", line 188, in sniff
    raise Error, "Could not determine delimiter"
_csv.Error: Could not determine delimiter
```

The CSV file:

```
input_gps,1424185824460,1424185902788,1424185939525,1424186019313,1424186058952,1424186133797,1424186168766,1424186170214,1424186246354,1424186298434,1424186376789,1424186413625,1424186491453,1424186606143,1424186719394,1424186756366,1424186835829,1424186948532,1424187107293,1424187215557,1424187250693,1424187323097,1424187358989,1424187465475,1424187475824,1424187476738,1424187548602,1424187549228,1424187550690,1424187582866,1424187584248,1424187639923,1424187641623,1424187774567,1424187776418,1424187810376,1424187820238,1424187820998,1424187916896,1424187917472,1424187919241,1424188048340,dummy-0,dummy-1,Total
-73.958315%2C 40.815569,0.0(nan%),1.0(100%),1.0(100%),0.0(nan%),1.0(100%),1.0(100%),0.0(nan%),1.0(100%),1.0(100%),0.0(nan%),1.0(100%),1.0(100%),0.0(nan%),1.0(100%),1.0(100%),1.0(100%),1.0(100%),1.0(100%),0.0(0%),0.0(nan%),0.0(0%),0.0(nan%),0.0(0%),0.0(nan%),0.0(nan%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(nan%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(nan%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(nan%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(nan%),0.0(0%),13.0 (42%)
-76.932984%2C 38.992186,0.0(nan%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(nan%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(nan%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(nan%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(nan%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),1.0(100%),0.0(nan%),1.0(100%),0.0(nan%),1.0(100%),0.0(nan%),0.0(nan%),1.0(100%),1.0(100%),1.0(100%),1.0(100%),1.0(100%),1.0(100%),1.0(100%),1.0(100%),0.0(nan%),1.0(100%),1.0(100%),0.0(nan%),1.0(100%),1.0(100%),0.0(nan%),1.0(100%),1.0(100%),0.0(nan%),0.0(0%),17.0 (55%)
null_input-0,0.0(nan%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(nan%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(nan%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(nan%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(nan%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(nan%),0.0(0%),0.0(nan%),0.0(0%),0.0(nan%),0.0(nan%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(nan%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(nan%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(nan%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(nan%),0.0(0%),0.0  (0%)
null_input-1,0.0(nan%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(nan%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(nan%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(nan%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(nan%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(nan%),0.0(0%),0.0(nan%),0.0(0%),0.0(nan%),0.0(nan%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(nan%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(nan%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(nan%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),0.0(nan%),1.0(100%),1.0  (3%)
Total,0.0(0%),1.0(3%),1.0(3%),0.0(0%),1.0(3%),1.0(3%),0.0(0%),1.0(3%),1.0(3%),0.0(0%),1.0(3%),1.0(3%),0.0(0%),1.0(3%),1.0(3%),1.0(3%),1.0(3%),1.0(3%),1.0(3%),0.0(0%),1.0(3%),0.0(0%),1.0(3%),0.0(0%),0.0(0%),1.0(3%),1.0(3%),1.0(3%),1.0(3%),1.0(3%),1.0(3%),1.0(3%),1.0(3%),0.0(0%),1.0(3%),1.0(3%),0.0(0%),1.0(3%),1.0(3%),0.0(0%),1.0(3%),1.0(3%),0.0(0%),1.0(3%),31.0(100%)
```

If you anyone can inform me how to workaround the problem or other alternative alternatives, it will be very helpful.

Comment: What does the CSV file look like? There is no single CSV standard, and there are many incompatibilities between different CSV formats. Python tries to guess the correct one, but in this case it can't for some reason...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker thanks a lot for your reply. From the link, you can download my testcase. It should re-produce the problem. And I know what delimiter would be in this is is is a comma(,). Is there anyway that I can define it? Instead CSV module try to guess?

Answer (score 1):

According to pypi, prettytable is only alpha level. I could not find where you could give it the configuration to pass to the csv module. So in that case, you probably should read the csv file by explicitely declaring the delimiter, and build the PrettyTable line by line

```
pt = None  # to avoid it vanished at end of block...
with open('/tmp/test.csv') as fd:
    rd = csv.reader(fd, delimiter = ',')
    pt = PrettyTable(next(rd))
    for row in rd:
        pt.add_row(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the same, working on some messier csv's. Ended up implementing fallback method with manual search

```
from string import punctuation, whitespace
from collections import Counter


def get_delimiter(self, contents: str):
    # contents = f.read()
    try:
        sniffer = csv.Sniffer()
        dialect = sniffer.sniff(contents)
        return dialect.delimiter
    except Error:
        return fallback_delimiter_search(contents)

def fallback_delimiter_search(contents: str) -> str:
    # eliminate space in case of a lot of text
    content_chars = list(filter(lambda x: (x in punctuation or x in whitespace) and x!=' ', contents))
    counts = Counter(content_chars)
    tgt_delimiter = counts.most_common(1)[0][0]
    return tgt_delimiter
```